# Close all programs ending in ".vshost.exe"

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Sometimes visual studio leaves programs running after they should have closed (and even after visual studio itself has closed).  These programs don't appear on the taskbar or in alt-tab when they are in this "ghost state".  By itself this wouldn't be too horrible, but I'm running programs off of an external drive and need to close them to eject said drive.  To make matters worse, I am unable to open task manager (it's blocked by group policy).

I currently use the `tasklist` command to manually check for such programs and then `taskkill` to close them.  However, this is a pain since it's easy to miss one.  I've seen the `taskkill /fi` switch but haven't been able to get it to work.

An example of a program with this name that I would want to close is `Program1.vshost.exe`.

In short: How can I easily close all programs whose names end in ".vshost.exe"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command could help:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3" %G in ('tasklist^|find /I ".vshost.exe"') do @echo %G %H %I
```

If output matches your criteria, then replace `@echo %G %H %I` with `taskkill /PID %H /T` or something similar to.

Note: `%` sign should be doubled when used in a batch script: use `%%G` instead of `%G`,  `%%H` instead of `%H` etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to add /F to the taskkill for it to work, though.  (`taskkill /F /PID %H /T`).

Answer (score 1):

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq *.vshost.exe"
```

Comment: When I run this I get the error message `ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized.`, which seems odd.